# React componentDidMount not firing and not updating state in electron app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Im creating a electron-react app and I'm using this boilerplate https://github.com/willjw3/react-electron

Im trying to fetch data from an API, Im able to get the data but im unable to update state using setState. componentDidMount is not firing as well. Am I setting something up wrong? Heres my code.

```
import React from "react"
import '../css/table.css'

const fs = window.require('fs');
const electron = window.require('electron')
const shell = electron.shell
const stockxAPI = window.require('stockx-api');
const stockX = new stockxAPI();

const scrapeStockx = (link, size) => {
    let lowestAsk 
    return stockX.fetchProductDetails(link)
        .then((response) => {
            let productData = response.variants
            //console.log(productData)
            for (let product of productData){
                if (product.size == size){
                    lowestAsk = product.market.lowestAsk
                    return '$' + lowestAsk
                }
            } 
    })
}
const fetchNewData = async (myProducts) => {
    for (let product of myProducts){
        let goatUrl = 'https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants?productTemplateId='
        let goatSKU = product.Goat[0].split('sneakers/')[1]
        let ogUrl = goatUrl + goatSKU

        let price = await scrapeStockx(product.Stockx[0], product.Size)
        product.Stockx[1] = price
        console.log('Product Size: ' + product.Stockx[1])
    }
    return myProducts
}

class ProductTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            Products : ''
        }
        this.renderTableData = this.renderTableData.bind(this)
        this.updateProducts = this.updateProducts.bind(this)
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({Products : 'Loading...'});
        let myProducts = await this.updateProducts()
        console.log('Component ' + myProducts)
        this.setState({Products : myProducts})
        console.log('Component' + this.state)
    }


    async updateProducts () {
        let rawData = fs.readFileSync('/Users/yunioraguirre/Desktop/Lucky Cops Item Tracker V1/Lucky Item Tracker/MyProducts.json')
        let myProducts = JSON.parse(rawData)

        //Updates Goat and Stockx Prices
        myProducts = await fetchNewData(myProducts)
        try {
            await fs.writeFileSync('MyProducts.json', JSON.stringify(myProducts, null, 2))
            console.log('Success!')
            console.log(myProducts)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        return myProducts
    }

    renderTableData = () => {
        return this.state.Products.map( product => {
            const {Id, Item, sku, Size, Sold, Goat, Stockx} = product
            return (
                <tr key={Id}>
                    <td>{Id}</td>
                    <td>{Item}</td>
                    <td>{sku}</td>
                    <td>{Size}</td>
                    <td>{product["Total Amount Paid"]}</td>
                    <td>{Sold}</td>
                    <td>{product['Price Sold For']}</td>
                    <td> <a href={Goat[0]} target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">{Goat[1]}</a></td>
                    <td> <a href={Stockx[0]} target='_blank' rel="noopener noreferrer">{Stockx[1]}</a></td>
                    <td> <a href={product['Flight Club'][0]} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{product['Flight Club']}</a></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    renderTableHeader = () => {
        console.log('State in Render' + JSON.stringify(this.state.Products))
        let header = Object.keys(this.state.Products[0])
        return header.map((key, index) => {
            return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div id='Table-Wrapper'>
                <h1 id='TableTitle'>Total Products</h1>
                <table id='Products Table'>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                        {this.renderTableData()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default ProductTable
```

Heres what I get in the console
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my code. As Drew stated, I needed a isLoading variable in state so I could render and fetch my data. Heres my updated State and ComponentDidMount

```
class ProductTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            Products : '',
            isLoading : true
        }
        this.renderTableData = this.renderTableData.bind(this)
        this.updateProducts = this.updateProducts.bind(this)
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let myProducts = await this.updateProducts()
        console.log('Component ' + JSON.stringify(myProducts))
        console.log('\n')
        await this.setState({Products : myProducts, isLoading : false})
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you provide an empty string as initial state. The first console log is from the `render` function and the second is from `this.renderTableHeader`. The problem happens when you hit this line: `let header = Object.keys(this.state.Products[0])`

```js
Object.keys(""[0])
```

You may want to try creating a separate "isLoading" state, and conditionally render JSX on that.

```
this.state = {
  Products : '',
  isLoading: false,
}

...

async componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({isLoading: true});
  let myProducts = await this.updateProducts()
  console.log('Component ' + myProducts)
  this.setState({Products: myProducts, isLoading: false})
}

....

render(){
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div id='Table-Wrapper'>
      <h1 id='TableTitle'>Total Products</h1>
      <table id='Products Table'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
          {this.renderTableData()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: HI I fixed my code but im still getting the same error, ComponentDidMount is not firing as i can't see the console.log in the console

Comment: I changed my isLoading to True and changed isLoading to False in componentDidMount and it seem to fire but now im getting a new error `Warning: can't perform a React state update on unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it Indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Comment: @NinoSoles That's actually just a warning, and a separate unrelated issue. *Some* call to `updateProducts` appears to have been made and still in-flight when the `ProductTable` unmounts. Like the warning suggests, any functions that asynchronously update component state need to be able to cancel the update should the component unmount. You can use an abort controller with fetch requests, and abort it in `componentWillUnmount`.